# Одновременное подключение заголовков Boost/thread.hpp и named_semaphore.hpp

Tags: c++, boost

Не удается скомпилировать программу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_semaphore.hpp>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Test start\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Собираю g++ под MinGW, boost версии 1_60, makefile:

```
BOOST_DIR = "d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0"
BOOST_LIB_DIR = "d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib"
BOOST_VERSION = 1_60
.PHONY: boost_semaphore
boost_semaphore: boost_semaphore.cpp
    g++ boost_semaphore.cpp -I${BOOST_DIR} -m32 -march=i686 -std=c++11  -static-libstdc++ 
        -o test.exe -L${BOOST_LIB_DIR} -lboost_system-mgw49-mt-${BOOST_VERSION} 
        -lboost_thread-mgw49-mt-${BOOST_VERSION} -lboost_chrono-mgw49-mt-${BOOST_VERSION}
```

При сборке выводит ошибки вида:

> In file included from
>   d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/interprocess/errors.hpp:41:0,
>                        from d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/interprocess/exceptions.hpp:24,
>                        from d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/interprocess/sync/named_semaphore.hpp:25,
>                        from boost_semaphore.cpp:3:
>       d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/interprocess/detail/win32_api.hpp:870:116:
>   warning: declaration of 'void*
>   boost::interprocess::winapi::CreateMutexA(boost::inter
>       process::winapi::interprocess_security_attributes*, int, const char*)' with C language linkage
>        extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void * __stdcall CreateMutexA(interprocess_security_attributes*, int, const char *);
>
> In file included from
>   d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:11:0,
>                    from d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15,
>                    from d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
>                    from boost_semaphore.cpp:2: d:\workspace\boost_1_60_0/boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp:171:55:
>   warning: conflicts with previous declaration 'void*
>   boost::detail::win32::CreateMutex
>   A(boost::detail::win32::_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES*, int, const char*)'
>                    __declspec(dllimport) void* __stdcall CreateMutexA(_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES*,int,char const*);

Я так понимаю идет переопределение функций причем с разными префиксами extern "c" и без, не понимаю как этого избежать?
Я не правильно буст собрал или необходимо использовать другие заголовочные файлы или специальные дефайны?

Comment: Это не ошибки, это предупреждения.

Comment: [Судя по всему](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Cmo5wMMoQSZZjYAO), неправильно собрали.

Comment: @alexolut, эти предупреждения не могут иметь отношения к сборке. Судя по всему это старая и [известная](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6145) проблема.

Comment: @ixSci, просто надо не для win собирать, вот и не будет предупреждений :) Вообще, конечно, удивляет, как долго могут жить известные баги в довольно крупных проектах.

Answer (score 1):

При сборке *boost* для *windows*, дабы не было разногласий в заголовочных файлах и подобных предупреждений, рекомендую добавлять дефайн `BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H`.

Если вы собираете boost утилитой `bjam.exe`, то к ее параметрам добавьте `define=BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H`. Если сборка идет через make, то используйте параметр `-DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H` для g++.